# What if setup.py has dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, pipenv

What do I do if `setup.py` in my pip installable package has dependencies?

For instance, in `setup.py` you will see:

```
from pipenv.project import Project
from pipenv.utils import convert_deps_to_pip
```

So that I can parse my pip package dependencies:

```
pfile = Project(chdir=False).parsed_pipfile
requires = convert_deps_to_pip(pfile['packages'], r=False)
```

and give them to `setup()`.

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires = requires,
    ...)
```

However, I cannot assume a user of this pip package has `pipenv` installed.
If I add `pipenv` as a dependency then `setup.py` will try to `import pipenv` before it is actually installed via `setup.py`.

Here is what happens if you try to pip install my package in a clean environment:

```
from pipenv.project import Project
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipenv'
```

If I `pip install pipenv` before running and then `pip install -e ./` in the project root the install works.

I can't think of a good solution...

Comment: You shouldn't put top-level imports in `setup.py` as the dependencies might not be installed yet (as you already found out). You can, however, add dependencies to `setup_requires` and import them in custom command implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer.  I will post it incase anyone ends up here. 
The answer is here: https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/advanced/#pipfile-vs-setup-py

`Pipfile` is intended for applications. 
However, libraries (packages) can still generate `Pipfile.lock` from `setup.py`.

```
$ pipenv install -e .
```